# Tkinter: Entry box value doesn't store into StringVar() object

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to see whether or not a value entered in the Entry widget is stored inside the StringVar() object but when I print the length of the string value object, it says 0.

```
class POS(tk.Tk):
def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    """
    some code to build multiple frames here
    """

class MainPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        frame5 = Frame(self, bg = "pink")
        frame5.pack(fill = BOTH)

        frame5Label1 = tk.Label(frame5, text = "Product Bar Code", font = NORMAL_FONT)
        frame5Label1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky = W)

        barCode = StringVar()
        frame5EntryBox = ttk.Entry(frame5, textvariable = barCode, width = 40)
        frame5EntryBox.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)

        frame5Button = ttk.Button(frame5, text = "Add Item", command = lambda: updateCustomerList(barCode))
        frame5Button.grid(row = 0, column = 2, padx = 130, pady = 10)


def updateCustomerList(barCode):
    print(len(barCode.get()))

app = POS()
app.geometry("700x700")
app.resizable(False,False)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You're calling the  print statement about 1 millisecond after you create the widget, and since you haven't given it a value, the value is the empty string.

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: How would I make it work with the button press? I did the same thing with the button press where I'd output the same print statement. I could add a sleep variable but if the user takes too long then it wouldn't work as well. Is there a wait to run that would work with these widgets?

Comment: Define a proper function to be used as button callback, call that `print` inside that function.

Comment: `mainloop()` starts program so your `len()` is executed even before tkinter displays window and when `frame5EntryBox` and `barCode` are still empty. Assign to button normal function with `print(len(barCode.get()))`. And don't forget to put some text in `frame5EntryBox` before you press button.

Comment: I've edited my question a little bit to showcase the structure of my code a little bit more clearly. I've tried putting the updateCustomerList function outside and inside the MainPage class to see if there's a difference but I either get a 0 (i.e. empty string) or that the updateCustomerList function is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimal working example which displays length of `StringVar` assigned to `Entry` after pressing `Button`

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def check():
    print('len:', len(var.get()))

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

var = tk.StringVar()

ent = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var)
ent.pack()

but = tk.Button(root, text="Check", command=check)
but.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

`mainloop` displays window with widgets so using `len()` before starting `mainloop` makes no sense because `var` is still empty.

---

**EDIT:** with your class and function outside class

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# --- classes ---

class MainPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        frame5 = tk.Frame(self, bg="pink")
        frame5.pack(fill="both")

        frame5Label1 = tk.Label(frame5, text="Product Bar Code", font="NORMAL_FONT")
        frame5Label1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")

        barCode = tk.StringVar()
        frame5EntryBox = ttk.Entry(frame5, textvariable=barCode, width=40)
        frame5EntryBox.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

        frame5Button = ttk.Button(frame5, text="Add Item", command=lambda:updateCustomerList(barCode))
        frame5Button.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=130, pady=10)

# --- functions ---

def updateCustomerList(barCode):
    print(len(barCode.get()))

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

main = MainPage(root, root)
main.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Or using `self.` and putting function inside class as  method

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# --- classes ---

class MainPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        frame5 = tk.Frame(self, bg="pink")
        frame5.pack(fill="both")

        frame5Label1 = tk.Label(frame5, text="Product Bar Code", font="NORMAL_FONT")
        frame5Label1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")

        self.barCode = tk.StringVar()
        frame5EntryBox = ttk.Entry(frame5, textvariable=self.barCode, width=40)
        frame5EntryBox.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

        frame5Button = ttk.Button(frame5, text="Add Item", command=self.updateCustomerList)
        frame5Button.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=130, pady=10)

    def updateCustomerList(self):
        print(len(self.barCode.get()))

# --- functions ---


# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

main = MainPage(root, root)
main.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I've been trying to replicate this into my code but since i've built multiple frames within the app, it gets confusing on where to put your "check" function. As of the current edited code I have up, I still have the same problem. I've tried to put the function before and after the __init__ MainFramePage function but it says that the function is not defined.

Comment: I would put this inside `MainFramePage` as its method and I whould use `self.barCode` so I could use it without `lambda`.

Comment: if you have error `"function is not defined"` then maybe you have wrong indentions and function is inside class but it has to be outside class.

Comment: I've tried the first one on your edit before and I still got a value of 0 (i.e. empty) and I've tried out using self and has the same answer: 0 (i.e. empty)

Comment: did you put text in `Entry` before you press button ? Or show full code - it can be link to external drive or GitHub or similar.

Comment: BTW: do you use two `Tk()` or two `mainloop()` in code ? It can make problem with `StringVar/IntVar/DoubleVar/etc.` because program should have only one `Tk()` and one `mainloop()`.

Comment: Here's the link to a gist: https://gist.github.com/apsdr3/21381bc818ea71537695c97b43145b16

Comment: Also I'm not entirely sure how to answer your question about the Tk() and mainloop(). I don't think I have multiples of them but I may be wrong.

Comment: you use `Tk` in `POS`, `MasterFilePopUp()` and `popupmsg`. You can also use second `mainloop`  in `popupmsg`. And you run `MasterFilePopUp` before `POS` so it runa `mailoop()` automatically. And it makes problem.

Comment: Ok, I get it. I'll try to see what I can do. Thanks!

Comment: see code after changes: I changed `MasterFilepopUp` and `popupmsg` and I run `MasterFilepopUp`  with `after()` so it starts after `mainloop` is running  https://gist.github.com/furas/c3f2af0eb375e50af0fb404eb2252b04 And now it shows correct length.